# Use a select query result in an other query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could please someone explain, how to use a result from a `SELECT` (1st select result)

Then use that result (1st select result) on a second query `VALUES` clause

there is an example (on Microsoft SQL Server) :

```
--1st query, select all DB1.client.name
select Name from DB1.client
--the result of that query is : 1st select result VALUES : ana,boby, ..., micky

--2nd query, compare DB1.client.name (1st select result) with DB2.client.name
--and get back who doesn't exist on second table
select v.Name
from (values 

**(There i want use the result of my first query)**

) as v(Name)
where not exists (select *
                  from DB2.client c
                  where c.Name = v.Name);
--the result is ana, ..., micky
```

"..." mean some other results

i want compare first and second database to retrieve values which aren't in both databases

Comment: That isn't how SQL works; you can't reference a prior data set in a latter one. If you need the same data, you either need to store it *somewhere* (such as a temporary table), or redefine the dataset again in the latter query (which could mean the data differs, if the underlying data *could* change).

Comment: Diid you see the first query is on Database1 and in the second query I use the result of first query to make the comparison with Database2?

Comment: In SQL Server, you can query multiple databases on the same instance.

Comment: So we can do what i ask, just how i can retrieve the result of first Database.Query on the second database VALUES clause?

Comment: Again, that isn't how SQL works. There is no "SELECT * FROM {The last query that returned a dataset}` YOu need to redefine the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, I recommend sub-query :

```sql
select Name
from DB1.client
where Name not in not exists (select name from DB2.client)
```

If you want reuse a query (not the result), see @Thkas answer.

It isn't possible to reuse the result in SQL Server, because SQL Server release the memory when the result is read. The trick is to insert the query's result in a temporary table, then you read this temporary table as many times as necessary :

```sql
--Insert into temporary table
insert into #tmpResult
select Name from DB1.client

--First read
select Name from #tmpResult

--Second read from sub-query
select Name
from #tmpResult
where Name not in not exists (select name from DB2.client)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample code I understood something like this. You can add two tables and do with `WHERE` the check you want.

```
select a.Name,b.Name
from DB1.client,
DB2.client as b 
where a.Name != b.Name;
```

Also if you want to take as a result set from the first query:
Here I created a subquery which takes the results from the first query. You can correct me for columns.

```
with temp as (
select Name 
from DB1.client
)select a.Name,b.Name
from temp as a ,
DB2.client as b 
where a.Name != b.Name;
```